# how search accented letter in a varchar2 column in oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, character-encoding

I have a varchar2 column named NAME_USER.
For example, the data is آصفی.
I have a query that searches the table to find rows that like some given character.
When I want to search for example اصفی it doesn't fetch anything!
But I want my query to fetches all different types of ( اَ  اِ  اٌ آ اُ ا ٲ ٳ ).

Is there any way to have a query that searches all types of a character not only the exact given one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I totally don't know the alphabet and language you use to be able to generate additional test cases. But what you are looking for is an accent-insensitive comparison, which is designated by `_AI` suffix for `NLS_SORT` parameter. For more information see [Globalization support guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-84F2A594-E641-4436-A903-D5D5B4D7FFA9).

Assuming this sample data:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> | ID | UNAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | آصفی |
> | 2 | اصفی |

You may use [`NLSSORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NLSSORT.html#GUID-781C6FE8-0924-4617-AECB-EE40DE45096D) function to tweak a single comparison:

> ```
> select
>   t.*,
>   nlssort(uname, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI') as nlskey
> from t
> where nlssort(uname, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
>   = nlssort('اصفی', 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')
> ```
>
> | ID | UNAME | NLSKEY |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | آصفی | 0xD8A7D8B5D981DB8C00 |
> | 2 | اصفی | 0xD8A7D8B5D981DB8C00 |

Or set such behaviour for the entire session and all comparisons:

> ```
> alter session set nls_sort=BINARY_AI
>
> alter session set nls_comp=linguistic
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> where uname = 'اصفی'
> ```
>
> | ID | UNAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | آصفی |
> | 2 | اصفی |

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize *script* you're using (Google Translator "discovered" it is Persian?) so here's example using Latin. I'm searching for strings that contain vowels `i` or `u`, regardless letter case (upper or lower; that's the last regexp_like parameter, `'i'`):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Littlefoot'  from dual union all
  3     select 'King Arthur' from dual union all
  4     select 'Lord Nelson' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col
  7  from test
  8  where regexp_like(col, 'i|u', 'i');

COL
-----------
Littlefoot
King Arthur

SQL>
```

As the last string, `Lord Nelson`, doesn't contain `i` nor `u`, it has not been returned.

Therefore, I presume that something like that should work for you as well, i.e. separate all sorts of that character with a pipe `|` sign and give it a try.